# How do you remove your originating IP from Thunderbird?

Tags: security, thunderbird, email

I'm in a peculiar position where I need to remove my IP address from my email headers (I have a pen name). I don't want my readers knowing who I am or where I live. I use Gmail to send out my emails with but I was able to find my IPv6 address in an email I sent to myself.

Comment: Instead of VPN/Tor, can you just use the Gmail web interface for these particular emails?

Answer (score 3):

You just can't. The IP address is not added there by your client but by the server which is the one adds the Header:

```
Delivered-To: highballer906@gmail.com
Received: by 10.60.17.1 with SMTP id k1csp74699oed; 
Mon, 17 Jun 2013 23:56:20 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.50.7.1 with SMTP id f1mr461112iga.48.1371538580627; 
Mon, 17 Jun 2013 23:56:20 -0700 (PDT) Return-Path: 
Received: from nm41-vm4.bullet.mail.ne1.yahoo.com (nm41-vm4.bullet.mail.ne1.yahoo.com. [98.138.120.220]) by mx.google.com
```

Those IP's are added there for your mail exchanger. Those ip's is to prevent abuse of their systems.

If you need to hide your ip, you should use a VPN or Tor or whatever that hides your ip from client side, but your mail client can and will not hide your ip address with any configuration.

Comment: Tor is insecure for my means as email protocol isn't encrypted so my exit node would be able to see the password to my Google account. That's not desired.

Comment: @KI4JGT I didn't said that you "should use Tor" but something that "hides your IP". If you need end-to-end encryption you should use SSL/TLS encryption for POP/SMTP since right now everyone is able to read your password and emails if you are not using them. https://ssd.eff.org/tech/email. So is either, you hide your IP and expose yourself to the risks or you don't hide yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason you want to hide your ip, you can do a vpn connection ot a remote vpn server in another country, and then send your emails. The performance is poor, but the recipients will get the ip of the vpn server instead.

Another option is to join the tor network. Look at the website [torptoject](https://www.torproject.org/) and how it works.

Comment: Tor is insecure for my means as email protocol isn't encrypted so my exit node would be able to see the password to my Google account. That's not desired.